# Asymptotics of Littlewood polynomials

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, conjectures

Littlewood in [L] states several conjectures regarding asymptotics of polynomials with $\pm1$ coefficients. 
He considers the class $\mathscr F$ of polynomials of form $\sum^n\pm z^m$ and asks whether there exists a sequence $f_n$ in $\mathscr F$ such that
$$A\leq\frac{|f_n(\theta)|}{\sqrt{n+1}}\leq B$$ 
for large n's.

**1.** I'd like to know if this is still open and would be grateful if someone could provide references for recent survey papers.

**2.** If the conjecture is not settled yet, I was thinking if one can apply integer programming methods to tackle the problem?

**Update 1** As pointed out by Fedor, J-P. Kahane's work gives an elegant proof for polynomials with unimodular coefficients. His result is as follows(I didn't translate it to English as seems rather easy to understand ):

> **Theoreme.** Il existe une suite de polynomes
>   $$P_n(z)=\sum_{m=1}^{n}a_{m,n}z^m,\,(|a_{m,n}| = 1; \, n=1,2,\ldots,m=1,\ldots,n)$$
>   et une suite $\epsilon_n$ positive tendant vers 0 telles que pour tout z de module 1 on ait$$(1-\epsilon_n)\sqrt{n}\leq|P_n(z)|\leq(1+\epsilon_n)\sqrt{n}.$$

Numerical experiments suggest there might be hope to construct a sequence of $P_n\in\mathbb  {Z}_2[x]$ which satisfies Kahane's asymptotics.

[L]*Littlewood, J. E.*, [**On polynomials $\sum^n\pm z^m, \sum^n e^{\alpha_mi}z^m, z = e^{\theta i}$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-41.1.367), J. Lond. Math. Soc. 41, 367-376 (1966). [ZBL0142.32603](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0142.32603).

Comment: J.-P. Kahane (Bull. London Math. Soc. 12 (1980), 321–342) answers this question in positive for polynomials with coefficients on the unit circle, and even proves that $A$ and $B$ may be arbitrarily close to 1. At least in this strength the question looks to be open. It was called open in a recent paper by A. Prikhodko (in which such polynomials are applied to spectral ergodic theory.)

Comment: What does $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ stand for in the edit - polynomials with $\pm 1$ coefficients? You may also look up Bombieri and Bourgain's 2009 paper in J. European Math. Soc. (Volume 11, Issue 3, 2009, pp. 627–703) for some significant quantitative improvement on Kahane's result.